# pgfplots: Boolean key for a style does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys, key-value

I trièd to insert a Bool `Title=true|false`:

```
\pgfplotsset{
%/pgfplots/.cd, % no effect
Title/.is choice, 
Title/.style={title={A title.}}, 
}
```

Why does `Title`,  `Title=true` and `Title=false` not work and I get a title both times? 
What do I have to make better?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
%/pgfplots/.cd, % no effect
Title/.is choice, 
Title/.style={title={A title.}}, 
}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Title=true]
\addplot[] {x} node[pos=0.5]{Has a title. :)};;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[Title=false]
\addplot[red] {x} node[pos=0.5]{Has a title too. :(};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: With `etoolbox`, something like `\pgfplotsset{Title/.code={\ifblank{#1}{}{\pgfplotsset{title={#1}}}}}` should do the trick. `.is choice` expects that you define a key for each choice. Not at a computer, can't test. If you really want to use `true` and `false`, how are you going to enter the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the handler `.is choice` that you define a key for each choice, then each of the different possible choices `true` or `false` should be given by a subkey.

```
\pgfplotsset{
  Title/.is choice, 
  Title/true/.style={title={A title.}},
  Title/false/.style={}, 
}
```

If you want to restrict the key to a boolean value, with the package `etoolbox`, you can use the handler `.is if`,

```
\pgfplotsset{Title/.is if,
  Title/.code={\ifbool{#1}{\pgfplotsset{title={A title}}}{}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, good. I wonder, why it worked here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560804/46023

Comment: @cis Actually, it doesn't work there. You can set the key `ShowPageFrame` to any value, and the output will not change since you don't pass the parameter (`true` or `false`) into its handler.

Comment: Ok, thx. But I wonder:   At such bool-keys, normally you do not have to say `Title=true,....`, it is `Title,...` enough. Could this be added here?